# QWizardPages to keep their own minimum sizes

Tags: c++, qt, qtgui

I'm working with Qt (**version 4.6** on Windows XP 32-bit and compiling in Qt Creator 2.0.0) and trying to get a QWizard to work out.

**First Problem**:

I have three **QWizardPages** in my **QWizard** so far. Each page has a QVBoxLayout applied as it's layout. My first page has very small content (just a three line QLabel) but for some reason there is quite a bit of white space between the QLabel and the "< Back", "Next >" and "Cancel" button pane. I want each page to have the minimum amount of white space based on the content inside it. In the past, when I've put a QVBoxLayout in a parentless QWidget (it's own window), the window was always just small enough to fix the QVBoxLayout. Now there is extra whitespace. Is there some option that I have to turn off or on so that the QWizardPages are as small as possible?

**Second** (and mostly likely related to the first) **Problem**:

Also, my second page is much larger than my first page, so when I get to the second page and come back to the first page, the first page maintains the same size as the second page but only after I have visited the second page. Is this a bug?

The only geometry setting I am doing is when I do a

```
move(50, 50);
```

in the QWizard constructor. No resizes... nothing explicit. I'm trying to let the layouts do their magic.

Thanks for your help in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this problem, I created a child class of QWizard and created a private slot like this:

```
void ChildClass::fitContents(int id)
{
    adjustSize(); // this automagically resizes the window to fit the contents
}
```

And made it had it called every time the page was changed, like so:

```
connect(this, SIGNAL(currentIdChanged(int)), this, SLOT(fitContents(int)));
```